# PhpStorm - Disable aligning class properties after refactoring

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 2021.2.1 on my Windows machine. The thing I've noticed today is when I refactor my class code it realign the class properties and methods parameters like so:

```php
public function __construct(
    public Notification $notification,
    public Post         $post,
    public ?Title       $title = null)
{
    //
}
```

How can I tell PhpStorm to not align class properties?

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces | Function declaration parameters | Align when multiline` -- disable that option and try again (invoke `Code | Reformat Code`).